# Different implementations of same object constructor not working with google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this object constructor:

```
// links object creator
function createLinksObject(id) {
  //constructor area
  this.mainFolderId = id;
  this.mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  this.mainFolderName = this.mainFolder.getName();
  this.mainFolderLink = this.mainFolder.getUrl();
  this.subFoldersArray = [];
  // function calling area
  addSubFolders(this.mainFolder, this.subFoldersArray);
  sortArray(this.subFoldersArray);
}
```

Which is properly working with this implementation of it:

```
var linksObject;

// generates links document
function linksDocument() {
  if (!showDevAlert("LINKS - HAHNE")) {
    return;
  }
  setTextStyle("A1:Z1000", "arial", 14, "center", "middle");
  createsHeaders("", "", "", "", "R00");
  setTitle("LINKS");
  linksObject = new createLinksObject(getParentFolderID());
  setMainFolderLink();
  setSubFoldersLinks(14);
  renameSheet("LINKS");
}
```

But I can't understand why my code won't run when I try to directly define linksObject inside my linksDocument() function.

```
// generates links document
function linksDocument() {
  if (!showDevAlert("LINKS - HAHNE")) {
    return;
  }
  setTextStyle("A1:Z1000", "arial", 14, "center", "middle");
  createsHeaders("", "", "", "", "R00");
  setTitle("LINKS");
  var linksObject = new createLinksObject(getParentFolderID());
  setMainFolderLink();
  setSubFoldersLinks(14);
  renameSheet("LINKS");
}
```

Or when I try to fully define it outside of my function.

```
var linksObject = new createLinksObject(getParentFolderID());

// generates links document
function linksDocument() {
  if (!showDevAlert("LINKS - HAHNE")) {
    return;
  }
  setTextStyle("A1:Z1000", "arial", 14, "center", "middle");
  createsHeaders("", "", "", "", "R00");
  setTitle("LINKS");
  setMainFolderLink();
  setSubFoldersLinks(14);
  renameSheet("LINKS");
}
```

Notes:

- setMainFolderLink() and setSubFoldersLinks(14) are the only two functions that
  are going to use the object linksObject.
- in any case, I'm only defining linksObject once, but in different places.

Comment: Is setTitle aslo using linksObject? and other setTextStyle, createsHeaders functions as well. you better to add the issue here.

Comment: Executing `var ____` inside a given scope defines it for that scope only. You should review different scope rules for JavaScript 1.6. in any case, it isn't clear what you mean by "my code won't run" since you show no usage information. Clearly if you execute `linksDocument` via the Script Editor menu then it has executed. Or are you expecting that Apps Script persists globals across separate invocations of Apps Script functions? It does not.

Comment: @Harshana the only two funtions using linksObject are the ones mentioned in my question (setMainFolderLink() and setSubFoldersLinks(14)). I've edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: @tehhowch I think I've understood what you said, and I've solved my problem by defining linksObject inside of linksDocument() and passing the object as a parameter for both functions that use it (setMainFolderLink() and setSubFoldersLinks(14)). So basically the problesm as you said was in my interpretation of local/global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the initial comments, I've come to the conclusion that the problem was with my interpretation of global/local scope.

After defining my object inside of linksDocument() and passing the object as a parameter for both functions that use it (setMainFolderLink() and setSubFoldersLinks(14)) it works just fine.

Final code is something in these lines:

```
// generates links document
function linksDocument() {
  ...
  var linksObject = new createLinksObject(getParentFolderID());
  setMainFolderLink(linksObject);
  setSubFoldersLinks(14, linksObject);
  ...
}
```